# Ionic push iOS handle loc-key parameter

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a native application on production that is being rebuilt using Ionic.
When sending push to this application in a certain situation the server (for iOS) uses a loc-key parameter.

> loc-key: A key to an alert-message string in a Localizable.strings
>   file for the current localization (which is set by the user’s language
>   preference). The key string can be formatted with %@ and %n$@
>   specifiers to take the variables specified in the loc-args array. See
>   Localized Formatted Strings for more information.
>   (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1)

Is there any plugin that creates Localizable.strings to handle this situation?

For now I'm using "ionic build ios", then I open the project on XCode and create manually the Localizable.strings. I tried to find a way to automatize this step but I had no success.
This application is being built by a Jenkins, but the release version need to be built manually because of this.

Additional info: This application is using phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I haven't found the solution.